# Substituting variables while reading text file

Tags: perl, perl-module, perl-data-structures

I have a text file as below and saved it as "file.txt"

```
"create variable $VAR alarm_object 0"
```

I am trying to read this in a perl script and printing it by substituting the "$VAR" variable

```
$VAR = TEMP_VAR
open (FILE,"<", "file.txt") or die $!;
        while (<FILE>) {
                chomp;
                eval(print "$_\n");
        }
        close (FILE);
```

I need the output as

```
"create variable TEMP_VAR alarm_object 0"
```

I tried to achieve this using eval function. It is not working as expected.

How can i achieve this in perl?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`eval`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/eval.html) is too heavy of a tool for this job.  Instead, just use a simple search and replace.

This basically substitutes `'$VAR'` with `$sub` for every line of your input file:

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use autodie;

my $sub = 'TEMP_VAR';

open my $fh, '<', 'file.txt';

while (<$fh>){
    print;             # Before
    s/\$VAR\b/$sub/g;
    print;             # After
}
```

Outputs:

```
"create variable $VAR alarm_object 0"
"create variable TEMP_VAR alarm_object 0"
```

Comment: Nor the while loop, seeing as it's just one line. But this way is a safer, more scalable approach, no?

Comment: Its working as mentioned above. File contains number of such Dollar Variables so while loop is required. correct?